# Proving image of continuous application

Tags: analysis, functions, continuity, connectedness

I am having a little bit of problem proving that the image of a function equals a certain set. The motivation behind is proving that $A$ is connected. More specifically, I am considering the following:

**Problem:**

Consider the sets
\begin{equation}
A \doteq\left\{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3} ; x^{2} / 4+y^{2}+z^{2} / 9=1\right\}
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
B \doteq\left\{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3} ; x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} =1\right\}
\end{equation}

Furthermore, consider the continuous function

\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
h: B \longrightarrow A \\
(\alpha, \beta, \gamma) \mapsto(2 \alpha, \beta, 3\gamma)
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}

**What I would like to prove is that $h\left(B\right) = A$**

**Attempt:**

I am a bit confused. However, my main motivation for guessing that $h\left(B\right) = A$ relies on the fact that:
$$
\frac{(2 \alpha)^{2}}{4}+\beta^{2}+\frac{(3 \gamma)^{2}}{9}=\frac{4 \alpha^{2}}{4}+\beta^{2}+\frac{9 \gamma^{2}}{9}=\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2}+\gamma^{2}=1
$$

For instance, in order to prove that $A \subset h\left(B\right)$, I would proceed as follows:

Let $v \in A$. Then, $v = \left(\alpha, \beta, \gamma \right)$ such that:
$$\alpha^{2} + \beta^{2} + \gamma^{2} =1$$

However, as previously discussed:
$$
\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2}+\gamma^{2} = \frac{(2 \alpha)^{2}}{4}+\beta^{2}+\frac{(3 \gamma)^{2}}{9} = 1
$$

which implies $v \in B$, but **not** $v \in h(B)$.

How can I prove that $h\left(B\right) = A$? Is the function well defined? I am definitely confused.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(x,y,z)\in B$, then $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$. But then$$\frac{(2x)^2}4+y^2+\frac{(3z)^2}9=1,$$and therefore $h(x,y,z)\in A$. So, $A\supset h(B)$. And if $(x,y,z)\in A$, then$$\frac{x^2}4+y^2+\frac{z^2}9=1,\tag1$$and therefore $(x,y,z)=h\left(\frac x2,y,\frac z3\right)$ and $(1)$ means that $\left(\frac x2,y,\frac z3\right)\in B$. So, $A\subset h(B)$.

Comment: I think you got a little confused about the sets $A$ and $B$, or am I mistaken? I am guessing that since you wrote that if $\left(x, y, z\right) \in A$ then $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=1$, but that property refers to $B$

Comment: Does that mean the function should map $A$ to $B$? I am confused

Comment: I've edited my answer. What do you think now?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to show that the function $h$ is surjective. Take $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma) \in A$ then $\frac{\alpha^2}{4}+\beta^2+\frac{\gamma^2}{9}=1$ then note that $(\frac{\alpha}{2}, \beta, \frac{\gamma}{3}) \in B$ such that $h((\frac{\alpha}{2}, \beta, \frac{\gamma}{3}))=(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$. Thus $h$ is surjective and hence $h(B)=A$.